# FullCalendar displayed at wrong time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fullcalendar

I'm implementing `FullCalendar` in a project, I've inserted some Events into the database and returned them to `Json`. But by displaying them on the screen, they come with the correct date time, but the display does not show in the correct place.

Example, the data comes with the bank start date of the event at 06:00, but are displayed at 10:00 in the morning.

In the image below, the event has start times at 06:30, and ends at 07:00.[image]

But it shows on the screen that the time is at 10:30[image]

My `Evento` Model:

```
 public class Eventos
 {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? end { get; set; }
    public int StatusEnum { get; set; }
 }
```

My `Controller`:

```
public JsonResult ObterEventos(string start, string end)
{
    var db = new AgendaOnlineFc();
    var dtInicial = Convert.ToDateTime(start).Date;
    var dtfinal = Convert.ToDateTime(end).Date;
    var lista = db.Eventos
        .Where(d => d.end < dtfinal && d.start > dtInicial)
        .ToList();
    return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My `Script`:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/Home/ObterEventos/'
});
```

And my Return Json

```
{ID: 10, title: "teste", start: "/Date(1495449000000)/"
, end: "/Date(1495450800000)/", StatusEnum: 0}
ID:10 StatusEnum:0 end:"/Date(1495450800000)/" start:"/Date(1495449000000)/" title:"teste"
```

Is there any additional configuration to be made? Or if not where am I going wrong in this implementation?

Comment: One word: Timezone.

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari  How I implement in code?

Comment: See if this works: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: '/Home/ObtenerEventos/,
        currentTimezone: 'America/Sao_Paulo'
    }
  });`

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari And in My controller. How I say that my TimeZone is this?

Comment: You don't. The timezone in your server looks like it is UTC. If your clients are in Brazil you just edit their timezone on the JS code.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Sorry, I'm a beginner. I do not know how to do...

Answer (score 2):

```
public DateTime start { get; set; }
public DateTime? end { get; set; }
```

use String instead and format it in following:

`rec.start = model.AllReservationsFromSchedule[i].start.ToString("s");`

model.AllReservationsFromSchedule[i].start is DateTime variable.

ToString("s") will generate string format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

After that your JSON will return correct date format for FullCalendar.

Comment: thanks so much for this. I had been banging my head against the wall for quite a while. I have been trying to use timezone: false to just return and display the time as stored in the database with no timezone adjustment .Local hosting and debugging my project showed correct results but when moved to the hosting service server the displayed time would be incorrect.